# onclick window.open (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, firefox, onclick, window.open

I have this line working just fine in Chrome but not in Firefox.
Any ideas why?

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored">                  
<i class="fa fa-edge" onclick='window.open("http://www.cnn.com");return false;'></i>
```

Comment: try putting the onclick on the button - firefox may not prevent the default action of the button if the click is on the icon

Comment: Well Pete , you are right .... (don't know why I didn't think about it). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pete suggested in the comments, put the "onclick" on the button.

Do this, I've tested it and it works:

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored" onclick='javascript:window.open("http://www.cnn.com", "cnn_name"); return false;'>                  
<i class="fa fa-edge"></i>
```